# VC06 neuron of c.elegans

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

My understanding was that all neurons and their synapses of worm c.elegans are already listed.

As source of this map I'm using following databases (both should contain same information):

[Connectivity Data](http://www.wormatlas.org/images/NeuronConnect.pdf)

[Database of Synaptic Connectivity of C. elegans for Computation](http://ims.dse.ibaraki.ac.jp/ccep/)

In both databases, neuro-motor neuron VC6 (aka VC06) has no synapses to any other neuron. This is surprising for me.

Is connectome of this animal finished? If it is, are these two databases up to date? Finally, if answer to previous questions is "yes", any explanation about this "isolated" neuron ?